# PutDistributedMapCache and FetchDistributedMapCache working in Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

How does the FetchDistributedMapCache and PutDistributedMapCache Works in Apache NIFI,
I have used the PutDistributedMapCache to Cache a record with the key but for the FetchDistributedMapCache I only have the Cache Entry identifier and Cache service, How can I get the value that we have just cached in PutDistributedMapCache